# Counting Choices & Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

**How many solutions are there in positive integers to the equation $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_4 = 16$? Suppose that one of these solutions is chosen at random, with all possibilities being
equally likely. What is the probability that the chosen solution has $x_1 = 5$?**

For the first part I know it is $15C12 = 455$. For the second part I substituted in $x_1=5$ to get $x_2 +x_3 +x_4 = 11$, which I then transformed into $y_2+y_3+y_4=8$, which has $10C8 = 45$ solutions. This gives a probability of $\frac{45}{455} = \frac{9}{91}$

**$(a)$Write an expression for the number of sets $S$ which contain $10$ elements, each of which is an integer between $1$ and $20$. $(b)$ How many subsets of S have size two?$(c)$For a non-empty subset $X ⊆ S$, let $t(X)$ denote the sum of the members of $X$. Prove that there must be distinct subsets $A,B ⊆ S$, each of size two, such that $t(A) = t(B)$.**

$(a)$ There are $20C10$ sets. $(b)$ I think this is wrong but I guess $10C2 = 45$. $(c)$ For the 3rd part, the number of subsets of size $2$ must have sums between $3$ and $39$, which is $37$ possible sums. However, there are $45$ possible subsets of size $2$, so by the pigeonhole principle there must exist two subsets with the same sum.

Comment: I agree with all of your work.  Parts (b) and (c) are poorly worded by the problem composer.  However, I think that you interpreted them as the problem composer intended.  For part (b), you are supposed to assume that there is some **fixed** set $S$ of $10$ distinct elements from $\{1,2,\cdots,20\}$.  You are then supposed to ask how many ways there are of selecting $2$ elements, from this **specific fixed** set $S$, sampling without replacement, where order of selection is regarded as irrelevant.  The computation is in fact $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{2}.$

Comment: Re previous comment, I am assuming that if the set $~S~$ equals $~\{1,2,\cdots,10\}, ~$ the set $~A = \{1,2\},~$ and the set $~B = \{1,3\},~$ that you are supposed to regard the sets $~A~$ and $~B~$ as **distinct.**  That is, you are supposed to ignore that they share the common element of $1$.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your reply. So you believe my answers are correct ? I agree that the question isn't fully clear. I was unsure for part $(c)$ because for the pigeonhole principle normally I would expect the pigeons to be $1$ more than the total number of pigeonholes.

Comment: Yes, I think that your answers are all correct.

Comment: Your answers are correct.  The number of pigeons merely needs to exceed the number of pigeonholes.